# How to escape {0} in tokenfile

Tags: c#, .net, tfs, token

I'm new to the use of tokenfiles and i've got myself in somewhat of a pickle.

My token-file looks af follows:

```
<tokens>
       <token name="URL.GETFILE" value="http://someserver.mycompany.com/virtual.directory/GetFile.aspx?file_id={0}" />
</tokens>
```

My web.config piece:

```
<configuration>
    ....
    <applicationSettings>
       <MyProject.My.Settings>
           <setting name="GetFileUrl" serializeAs="String">
               <value>http://somedvlpserver.mycompany.com/virtual.directory/GetFile.aspx?file_id={0}     </value>
           </setting>
       </MyProject.My.Settings>
    </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

My transformfile:

```
  <setting name="GetFileUrl" serializeAs="String" xdt:Locator="Match(name)">
    <value xdt:Transform="Replace">{URL.GETFILE}</value>
  </setting>
```

While building the solution i'm getting the error:

```
No value or default value found for token '0'
```

Could the `{0}` in my tokenfile somehow interefere with the transformation? If so how make the transformation ignore it?

Thank you for your time

Comment: Not yet. Will try it immediatly.

Comment: backslash didn't work. Will try double brackets now

Comment: Yep double brackets did solve the problem. Any idea where i can find more information about the use of double brackets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `string.Format` you use double braces, `{{` and `}}` to encode literal `{`, `}`. I'm not familiar with that particular API/format, but it seems to have the same behaviour.

From the [`string.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx) documentation:

> **How do I include literal braces (`"{"` and `"}"`) in the result string?**
>
> A single opening or closing brace is always interpreted as the beginning or end of a format item. To be interpreted literally, it must be escaped. You escape a brace by adding another brace (`"{{"` and `"}}"` instead of `"{"` and `"}"`),

---

In general, doubling or backslash escaping are the most popular techniques for dealing with characters with a special meaning. So when confronted with an unknown format, try both of these and you have good chances that one of them works.

Comment: Sweet! Thank you for the solution & documentation!